# MySQL ignoring Force Index for Delete Query, But Not For Equivalent Select Query

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization, sql-delete, force-index

I am extremely confused and frustated here -

I have a table (table1) that is enormous.

I am trying to do a delete query based on another table.  The query optimizer isn't using the appropriate index, so I am trying to force it

```
delete table1 
FROM table1
FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (index1)  
inner JOIN table2  
where
table1.field1=table2.field1
and
table1.field2=table2.field2
and
date(table1.startdatetime)=table2.reportdate;
```

The equivalent select looks as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (index1)  
inner JOIN table2  
where
table1.field1=table2.field1
and
table1.field2=table2.field2
and
date(table1.startdatetime)=table2.reportdate;
```

What I don't understand is that the delete query does not use the index, but the select query does

The "explain" from the select is:

```
1   SIMPLE  table2 index    idx1    idx1    55      1456    Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  table1 ref  index1 index1 51    table2.field1,table2.field2 508 **Using index condition**
```

But the explain for the delete is as follows:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, SIMPLE, table2, index, idx1, idx1, 55, , 1456, Using where; Using index
1, SIMPLE, table1, ref, index1, index1, 51, table2.field1,table2.field2, 508, Using where
```

Why does the select statement have **Using index condition** and the equivalent delete have **using where**?

How can I force the delete to use the index also?

Thank you!

Comment: It's often quicker to create a new table, retaining only the desired data, then drop the source table, then rename the new table

Comment: That is not really practical when the table in question is 1TB and the deleted amount is less than 1% of that..    Thanks for the idea tho

Comment: Well it's practical if it's faster

Comment: Hard to help you without `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables and the MySQL version you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Index hints apply only to SELECT statements. (They are accepted by the
>   parser for UPDATE statements but are ignored and have no effect.)

from [the official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html)

Even though it is not specifically called out, I'd assume DELETE falls under how UPDATE is handled, rather an SELECT.

Comment: Thanks... what a remarkably stupid and random way to implement functionality.

Comment: Newer versions have made the Optimizer common between SELECT and DML statements.

Comment: The page followed "the official docs" link no longer has the quoted sentence.

Answer (score 0):

An inefficiency may be

```
date(table1.startdatetime)=table2.reportdate
```

No index on `startdatetime` can be used because it is hiding inside a function call.  Usually better is to do:

```
    table1.startdatetime >= table2.reportdate
AND table1.startdatetime  < table2.reportdate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```